# too much recursion error

Tags: jquery, recursion

I am showing images one by one.. But it displays two images at a time... Why this strange behavior?

```
<div Id="BannerDiv">
  <img src="images/CIOT flash/im_01.png" alt="image1"/>
  <img src="images/CIOT flash/im_02.png" alt="image2"/>
  <img src="images/CIOT flash/im_03.png" alt="image3"/>
  <img src="images/CIOT flash/im_04.png" alt="image4"/>
  <img src="images/CIOT flash/im_05.png" alt="image5"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#BannerDiv > :first').show();
    setTimeout(rotate,1000);
  });

  function rotate() {
    var c = jQuery('#BannerDiv > :visible').css({ 'z-index': 2 }).fadeOut(2000, function() {
      setTimeout(rotate, 1000);
    }).next().css({ 'z-index': 1 }).show();
    if (c.length == 0) jQuery('#BannerDiv > :first').css({ 'z-index': 1 }).show();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Try to use setTimeout( function() { rotate();}, 1000);  I didn't check the rotate function but please use the code sample markup (icon 101 010) and line-breaks so that it is much clearer to identify the issues ;)

Comment: Works for me: http://www.jsfiddle.net/2BscT/1/. What version of jQuery... what markup?

Comment: Michael - the code you suggest is exactly the same

Comment: Mubeen - can you paste your markup. It could be that the fadeOut is being triggered multiple times thus triggering the setTimeout multiple times if you have many matches to the jQuery('#BannerDiv > :visible') selector.

Comment: @redsquare : it's almost the same but this format is preferred as it won't invoke 'eval', allows for more complex logic and grants some nifty closure action.

Comment: @Michael Lumbroso, I have to disagree - how in this scenario are the extra keystrokes and the fact it makes debugging harder due to the anonymous method, is it 'preferred'

Comment: @Michael: If he were to do `setTimeout("rotate()", 1000);`, then `eval()` will be used, but both code snippets pass functions as references, so eval is not used.

Comment: @Michael you should **learn Javascript before you argue**. setTimeout(rotate,1000); will not invoke eval. rotate is passed by reference, just as your solution's anonymus function.

Comment: @Mubeen: Even with your new markup, this still works for me: http://www.jsfiddle.net/2BscT/2/

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys i had this very problem 'Too much recursion & also Stack Overflow error' doing image cycles too check
http://callmenick.com/post/instantiation-patterns-in-javascript

its called Functional Instantiation or Closures, returning values etc. can fix it.

If you go to this git repo http://github.com/rebornweb/neoscript

and go to image_cycles folder and the html dreimage_cycler.html will have the code that works :)

Cheers